# youtube api v3 fetch all videos from a channel that are newer than a video

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

I already have a script to get all videos information from a youtube channel and store them in a database. Now I want to update my database in case new videos have been uploaded to that channel. How do I retrieve videos that are newer than the newest video in my database?

I have the channelTitle of the channel, videoId and publishedAt of the newest video in the database.

Comment: then check is the publishedAt is different from you publishedAt stored in your database. Don't see the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074112/youtube-api-3-get-latest-videos

Comment: your solution is very inefficient if a channel has hundreds or thousands of videos. @mpgn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the publishedAfter parameter for your search query. See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters

Comment: As a side note, this is **not** supported with `videos/list`. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list