# YouTube API: why can't I see latest video for this channel?

Tags: youtube-api

The latest video for this channel shows up when viewed via the Youtube website:
https://www.youtube.com/user/stefbot/videos

(video ID [a4pPLwAL_Qo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4pPLwAL_Qo))

However that video does not get returned when the channel is queried via the Youtube API. I retrieve the channel video list by making a call to `channels`, followed by a call to `playlistItems` e.g.:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername=stefbot&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUC3L8QaxqEGUiBC252GHy3w&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

See playlist response JSON [here](https://ghostbin.com/paste/jaaja)

It has been more than 24hrs since this video was posted. Can someone explain why the API would not be returning the latest video for this channel?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [support page](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/58097?hl=en), it can take a few days for uploaded videos to be reflected in YouTube search results, especially if you recently changed or removed your video. Also, you can use this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32096906/5832311) and use  [`Search: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) to get the latest videos from user's uploads.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&maxResults=10&order=date&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: I get feeds from half a dozen other channels using the same method, and none of the others have a delay like this one. Also, not all videos are delayed for this channel - some appear straight away, some never appear i.e. there are gaps in the timeline!